# Как сделать чтобы дата окончания не могла быть меньше даты старта?

Tags: javascript

Есть код выбора даты старта и окончания, как сделать, так чтобы дата окончания не могла быть меньше даты старта или при выборе даты старта в поле дата окончания сразу изменялась на ту же дату и время+15 минут. Например: Если дата старта выбрана 2016-02-10 16:00:00, то в поле даты окончания сразу поставилось 2016-02-10 16:15:00 как-то так...

код:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#start_date').datetimepicker({
        lang:'ru',
        timepicker:false,
        format:'Y-m-d',
        value:'<? echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>'
    });

    jQuery('#start_time').datetimepicker({
        lang:'ru',
        datepicker:false,
        format:'H:i',
        value:'<?=date('H'); ?>:00',
        step:15
    });

    jQuery('#end_date').datetimepicker({
        lang:'ru',
        timepicker:false,
        format:'Y-m-d',
        value:'<? echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>'
    });

    jQuery('#end_time').datetimepicker({
        lang:'ru',
        datepicker:false,
        format:'H:i',
        value:'<?=date('H')+1; ?>:00',
        step:15
    });
});
```

Comment: именно на нем, как сделать то?

Comment: Прошу прощения случайно удалил, сейчас найду в своем старом коде, я уже такое реализовывал, а вообще у них там в мануале все написано если что.

Answer (score 1):

После того как Вы выбрали дату или время во from Вам нужно сделать

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
        $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
        });
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
    });
</script>
```

И будет Вам счастье, он и в ту и в ту сторону блокирует в зависимости от того где и что Вы выбрали ))) Если что плагин тут https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

А если вы используете [этот](https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) то почти все тоже самое только вот параметры

```
$.fn.datetimepicker.defaults = {
  maskInput: true,           // disables the text input mask
  pickDate: true,            // disables the date picker
  pickTime: true,            // disables de time picker
  pick12HourFormat: false,   // enables the 12-hour format time picker
  pickSeconds: true,         // disables seconds in the time picker
  startDate: -Infinity,      // set a minimum date
  endDate: Infinity          // set a maximum date
};
```

и Вам там нужно выставлять соответственно **startDate** и **endDate**

тем самым вы будите ограничивать календарь выбираемыми датами + не забываем делать `$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('update');`

Comment: чет у меня другое как-то...

Comment: Если что плагин тут https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/